# Best port to setup Outline VPN for obfuscation

Tags: http, vpn, ports, obfuscation, isp

Many outline access keys use a random port but some do 443, I’ve found out since port 443 is for http its harder to find out that port is using a vpn.

So the question is, why don’t other Outline servers use port 443 instead of a random port? Which will be more obfuscated for ISP’s?

Comment: 443 might be in use because overzealous networks like to block all ports except for those required.  HTTP/HTTPS is required in most people's book and under encryption VPN traffic can be made to look a bit like HTTPS to fly under this blocking.